# Loop through JSON response object

Tags: jquery, json

I get a response from an API like below. How can I loop through the results using jQuery to access the value for 'appName' for example?

```
var apps = 
{ 
  358899126: 
   { appId: 358899126,
     appName: 'Tagged -Chill, Chat & Go Live!',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Social Networking' },
  359917414: 
   { appId: 359917414,
     appName: 'Solitaire',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Games' } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get the key of each object, and then use he square bracket syntax to get the actual object, like so:

```js
var apps = 
{ 
  358899126: 
   { appId: 358899126,
     appName: 'Tagged -Chill, Chat & Go Live!',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Social Networking' },
  359917414: 
   { appId: 359917414,
     appName: 'Solitaire',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Games' } 
}

Object.keys(apps).forEach((key) => {
  let obj = apps[key];
  console.log(obj.appName);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Object.keys` to get all indexes of an object as an array and then loop through them.Try this.

```
var apps = 
{ 
  358899126: 
   { appId: 358899126,
     appName: 'Tagged -Chill, Chat & Go Live!',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Social Networking' },
  359917414: 
   { appId: 359917414,
     appName: 'Solitaire',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Games' } 
}
let k = Object.keys(apps);
for(var s = 0 ; s < k.length ; s++)
{
    console.log(apps[k[s]]['appName'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var apps = 
{ 
  358899126: 
   { appId: 358899126,
     appName: 'Tagged -Chill, Chat & Go Live!',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Social Networking' },
  359917414: 
   { appId: 359917414,
     appName: 'Solitaire',
     primaryCategoryName: 'Games' } 
}

for(var k in apps){
  console.log(apps[k].appName);
}
```

Loop will iterate through keys, for accessing the appName use the dot operator or can be done other way `console.log(apps[k]["appName"]);`.

Hope this will help you.